# How do I specify a time for the html slider show to automatically skip it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I brought a slider show, but it can only be turned over manually and I want both manual and automatic. I want to automatically slide over every second.
Currently, users are allowed to turn slides manually by pressing a button, but they want to implement automatic flipping at intervals of 1 second.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  height: 265px;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-left,
.w3-right,
.w3-badge {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-badge {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="col w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/7af8c6f6-253b-447f-9fdf-274b03037ab6subjectImg.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/ca557505-2927-409c-a049-ef2a17dc2070KakaoTalk_20181202_043105760.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/a16a9e10-7c2f-44bc-9ee2-8843ae72fbc3umr.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/ca557505-2927-409c-a049-ef2a17dc2070KakaoTalk_20181202_043105760.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}

 //set 1 for forward and set -1 for backword
    setInterval(() => {
        plusDivs(1)
    }, 1000)
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  height: 265px;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-left,
.w3-right,
.w3-badge {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-badge {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="col w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/7af8c6f6-253b-447f-9fdf-274b03037ab6subjectImg.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/ca557505-2927-409c-a049-ef2a17dc2070KakaoTalk_20181202_043105760.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/a16a9e10-7c2f-44bc-9ee2-8843ae72fbc3umr.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://neitter.s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/users_penpal_photo/ca557505-2927-409c-a049-ef2a17dc2070KakaoTalk_20181202_043105760.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the bottom of your script

`setInterval(() => { plusDivs(1) },1000)` (to go forward)

`setInterval(() => { plusDivs(-1) },1000)`(to go backward)

Change the `1000` (its in ms) if you wish to adjust the speed.